# Symmetric spaces in Cartan's moving frame method

Tags: riemannian-geometry

What is the condition on the curvature 2-form $\Omega^i_j$ in Cartan's formalism for it to be parallel?

Comment: Offhand, I don't see how to do it simpler than: If $R_{ijikl}$ are the comments of the curvature tensor with respect to a frame and $\omega^i_j$ are the connection $1$-forms, then parallel curvature means $$0 = \nabla R_{ijil} = dR_{ijkl} - R_{pjkl}\omega^p_i - R_{ipkl}\omega^p_j - R_{ijpl}\omega^p_k - R_{ijkp}\omega^p_l$$